# How to extract partial string based on the percentage of the length of dataframe elements?

Tags: r

```
str1 <- c("youaremyfriend","youarethebest")
str2 <- c("ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","thisismydata","thereisabird")
df <-c(str1，str2)
#the ideal research 
"youar" "youa" "ABCDE" "this" "ther"
```

Hello, I want to extract the first one-third of string from all elements of df. For example, "youaremyfriend" the length is 14，so the result should be "youar". How can I do that? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `stringr` this can be done like this:

```
library(stringr)
str1 <- c("youaremyfriend","youarethebest")
str2 <- c("ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","thisismydata","thereisabird")

string <- c(str1, str2)

str_sub(string, start = 1, end = round(str_length(string)/3))
# [1] "youar" "youa"  "ABCDE" "this"  "ther"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string, you can use built-in functions `nchar` and `substring` (no libraries needed)

```
str1 = "youaremyfriend"
str1_length = nchar(str1)
substring_wanted = substr(str1, 1, round(str1_length/3)

"youar"
```

Comment: I dont disagree with rounding, but I think just letting integer truncation happen would also be fine +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but doesn't `substr(str1, 1, 4.67)` and `substr(str1, 1, round(4.67))` yield different results?

Comment: Yes, but my point is that there is no such thing as a partial letter, so you're either one over a third, or one under a third (or perhaps exact, in the case that the number of characters in the string be a multiple of 3).

Comment: Oh I see, makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in base R:

```
str1 <- c("youaremyfriend", "youarethebest", "BBBAAAKKK")
str2 <- c("ABCDEFGHIJKLMN", "thisismydata", "thereisabird")
df <- data.frame(str1, str2)

c(apply(df, c(1, 2), function(s) {
  strtrim(s, width = nchar(s)/3)
}))
```

Your first column was missing an entry so I added one to construct the dataframe.